# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int' using tensorflow_lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am using this code in tensorflow and it is working fine but not working in tensorflow_lite. can anyone explain how i can write below code without getting this error.

> `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'`

arr1 = arr.flatten()

tmp = np.argmax(arr1)

if arr1[tmp] > 0:

Comment: What is the dtype of `arr1`? If it's object, then what's the dtype of `arr[1tmp]`? Or what's a sample of `arr1[tmp]`?

Comment: Just based on the error message, arr1[tmp] seems to return a `function` type. How is arr defined in your code?

Comment: Hi @JaredJunyoungLim the arr is defined like this                                                        arr = np.asarray(det)